# Converting nonstandard string dates into date objects in R

Tags: r, date

I have a dataframe that contains a column V8 which consists of string values in this format --

```
7/16, 02/11, 5/12
```

These items are dates, the first representing the month of July in the year 2016, the second representing February of 2011, and the last representing May 2012. Sometimes there are initial zeroes, other times there are not.

I would like to represent these dates as such in R using the `as.Date` method, but I know that this representation is nonstandard and ambiguous.

I was going to resort to programmatically converting the values in the CSV file to representations that would be understood by `as.Date`, but it struck me that this must be a common problem so there might be a less involved and more idiomatic solution. I found the `strptime` function but I am not clear on how to use it, tried `strptime("09/12", format="%m/%y")` but it returns `NA`.

How can I convert these non-standard string values into Date objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to use `as.Date()` and assume that each of your months occurs on the first of the month:

```
> strDates <- c("07/16", "02/11", "05/12")
> dates <- as.Date(paste0("01/", strDates), "%d/%m/%y")
> dates
[1] "2016-07-01" "2011-02-01" "2012-05-01"
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly for my purposes.

Answer (score 3):

One potential fix is using `as.yearmon()` from the zoo package.

```
> as.yearmon("09/12", format ="%m/%y")
[1] "Sep 2012"
```

The only downside of this is that you do not get a "Date" object but instead get a "yearmon" object.

Comment: +1 for a solution which preserves just the information in the original format.  Can also be converted to Date as follows if required: `library(zoo); as.Date(as.yearmon("09/12", format ="%m/%y"))`

Answer (score 1):

The `lubridate` package might come in useful for this:

```
library(lubridate)
strDates <- c("07/16", "02/11", "05/12")
as.Date(parse_date_time(strDates, orders="%m/%y"))
[1] "2016-07-01" "2011-02-01" "2012-05-01"
```